# M4A Tagging Issues

Tags: id3, m4a

I'm having an issue with inserting M4A atoms into a file. Since the original file does not have a udta structure, I added it using an existing M4A file I had lying around as a guide.

Here's what I did to add the atoms:

1. Build a udta atom in memory
2. Update the size of the moov atom to include to size of the udta atom
3. Copy the file up to the end of the first trak atom
4. Insert my udta atom
5. Copy the rest as usual.

The only real difference between the original file and tagged file is that the mdat atom has been moved down a little to accommodate the tags. This leads me to believe that there's some reference to that position in the other atoms, but I couldn't find one.

Here is the output from AtomicParsley:

Original File:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 36, ends @ 36
Atom moov @ 36 of size: 30156, ends @ 30192
     Atom mvhd @ 44 of size: 108, ends @ 152
     Atom iods @ 152 of size: 33, ends @ 185
     Atom trak @ 185 of size: 30007, ends @ 30192
         Atom tkhd @ 193 of size: 92, ends @ 285
         Atom mdia @ 285 of size: 29907, ends @ 30192
             Atom mdhd @ 293 of size: 32, ends @ 325
             Atom hdlr @ 325 of size: 37, ends @ 362
             Atom minf @ 362 of size: 29830, ends @ 30192
                 Atom smhd @ 370 of size: 16, ends @ 386
                 Atom dinf @ 386 of size: 36, ends @ 422
                     Atom dref @ 394 of size: 28, ends @ 422
                 Atom stbl @ 422 of size: 29770, ends @ 30192
                     Atom stts @ 430 of size: 24, ends @ 454
                     Atom stsd @ 454 of size: 106, ends @ 560
                         Atom mp4a @ 470 of size: 90, ends @ 560
                             Atom esds @ 506 of size: 54, ends @ 560
                     Atom stsz @ 560 of size: 26888, ends @ 27448
                     Atom stsc @ 27448 of size: 40, ends @ 27488
                     Atom stco @ 27488 of size: 2704, ends @ 30192
Atom mdat @ 30192 of size: 2495503, ends @ 2525695
```

Modified file:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 36, ends @ 36
Atom moov @ 36 of size: 30323, ends @ 30359
     Atom mvhd @ 44 of size: 108, ends @ 152
     Atom iods @ 152 of size: 33, ends @ 185
     Atom trak @ 185 of size: 30007, ends @ 30192
         Atom tkhd @ 193 of size: 92, ends @ 285
         Atom mdia @ 285 of size: 29907, ends @ 30192
             Atom mdhd @ 293 of size: 32, ends @ 325
             Atom hdlr @ 325 of size: 37, ends @ 362
             Atom minf @ 362 of size: 29830, ends @ 30192
                 Atom smhd @ 370 of size: 16, ends @ 386
                 Atom dinf @ 386 of size: 36, ends @ 422
                     Atom dref @ 394 of size: 28, ends @ 422
                 Atom stbl @ 422 of size: 29770, ends @ 30192
                     Atom stts @ 430 of size: 24, ends @ 454
                     Atom stsd @ 454 of size: 106, ends @ 560
                         Atom mp4a @ 470 of size: 90, ends @ 560
                             Atom esds @ 506 of size: 54, ends @ 560
                     Atom stsz @ 560 of size: 26888, ends @ 27448
                     Atom stsc @ 27448 of size: 40, ends @ 27488
                     Atom stco @ 27488 of size: 2704, ends @ 30192
     Atom udta @ 30192 of size: 167, ends @ 30359
         Atom meta @ 30200 of size: 159, ends @ 30359
             Atom ilst @ 30212 of size: 147, ends @ 30359
                 Atom ©ART @ 30220 of size: 35, ends @ 30255
                     Atom data @ 30228 of size: 27, ends @ 30255
                 Atom ©nam @ 30255 of size: 63, ends @ 30318
                     Atom data @ 30263 of size: 55, ends @ 30318
                 Atom ©alb @ 30318 of size: 41, ends @ 30359
                     Atom data @ 30326 of size: 33, ends @ 30359
Atom mdat @ 30359 of size: 2495503, ends @ 2525862
```

Another thing of note is that the tagged file I'm using as reference has an hdlr atom under udta->meta, but adding a copy of that tag didn't help either. If I manually remove the udta atom and the size data of moov, the file works again.

When I try to play the tagged file, I get these errors in various programs:

```
mplayer:
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 0.0 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 0.0 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 3.13 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 2.14 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 2.9 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 3.1 is not allocated
    [aac @ 0x204d720] channel element 0.3 is not allocated
    ....
totem:
    ** Message: Error: Could not decode stream.
    gstfaad.c(1319): gst_faad_chain (): /GstPlayBin2:play/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFaad:faad0:
    decoding error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification
banshee:
    [Error 08:26:27.610] GStreamer stream error: Decode
    [Error 08:26:27.960] GStreamer stream error: Decode
    [Error 08:26:28.252] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
```

Oh, how I wish the other 99% of programs recognized ID3 tags on files other than MP3's....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to xdelta3, I was able to locate the difference between a file tagged with tagging software and then manually removed and the original file.

The issue appears to be the 'stco' atom, which is a list of chunks using absolute file offsets. Bingo! Since I added tags, those offsets are now invalid. More coding to do *sigh*